# Your browser does not support the video tag on safari

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

So on my website I have one small video, I have two file types, mp4 and webm. Webm seems to be working for mozilla, chrome, while mp4 works on explorer, and should work on Safari. It doesn't. I can't grasp what it is, I've tried to add .ogg and .mov tags, still not working, I added the extensions to htaccess, still nothing.

```
<video width="600" height="400" controls>
            <source src="img/sms.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="img/sms1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

This is the code, works everywhere except safari, which makes it not work on any apple devices, as far I'm aware(tested on an iPhone, not working).

Comment: Is the "Your browser does not support the video tag." message actually displaying on Safari or is the video simply not appearing?

Comment: The message is displaying on safari, if I remember correctly, you can see a play button on an iPhone but can't actually press it to play the video. I added a flash fallback to it, there is a white box in place of the video, but when I right click it it says video not loaded

Comment: That is very weird, Safari has supported the video tag since version 4! But, is Quicktime installed on the system? Safari requires Quicktime to run HTML5 video.

Comment: I probably should have said that it's safari for windows, I use it to check locally if the video is working. So I'll download the plugin for safari, but what about iPhone?

Comment: I suspect the video is not in the right format for iPhone, there are a number of MP4 flavours. I would suggest downloading Miro Video Converter and use that to convert your video.

Comment: I tried different converters, different types of mp4, I ended up embedding a youtube video instead